# Why no short overloads for std::to_string? Why no noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does anybody know why the various `to_string` functions declared in section 21.5 of the C++11 standard lack overloads for short and unsigned short?  How about why these functions are not declared `noexcept`?  This is the full set of overloads:

```
string to_string(int val);
string to_string(unsigned val);
string to_string(long val);
string to_string(unsigned long val);
string to_string(long long val);
string to_string(unsigned long long val);
string to_string(float val);
string to_string(double val);
string to_string(long double val);
```

I looked at the the proposals that led to these functions being adopted (N1803, N1982, N2408), but none of them have any motivation or rationale.

If I'm violating protocol by putting two (rather related, IMO) questions in a single post, I apologize.  I'm still new at SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exceptions: there's no `noexcept` constructor for `std::string`, so that's just not possible (i.e. the string memory allocation may fail).

Shorts: All integral types that are default-promoted are missing; I suppose there'd just be nothing to be gained from supporting them. By contrast, the longer types may be more expensive, so `int` should be offered for the space conscious.

Comment: Wouldn't that be performance (as in runtime) conscious? Afterall while the conversion is likely to be more expensive, there isn't any need to actually store the longer type.

Comment: @Grizzly: Yes, space *and* time efficiency may be affected by using a needlessly long type.

Comment: int not only is a nice thing but required. passing a short to the overload set missing the int overload will give an ambiguity (on a non-16 bit box).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I think the "bitness of your box" doesn't affect the conversion ranks of integral promotion, does it?

Comment: @kerr not for short (i apologize) but for unsigned short. if it doesnt fit into an int, the promotion is to unsigned int.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I see your point now. I was being elliptic, though, and I always meant my argument to apply in parallel to both a signed and an unsigned type, so there would never be an issue of signedness conversion.

Answer (score 4):

These functions all do arithmetic on the value that's passed to them. Types that are smaller than int are promoted to int (or unsigned int) for arithmetic, so there's no computational benefit from having versions that take types smaller than int. (These came in through my proposal, so I know the history intimately)

Comment: One annoying feature of not having some of the types smaller than int is compiler warnings. For instance to_string of an unsigned char on GCC gives "passing ‘unsigned char’ chooses ‘int’ over ‘unsigned int’ [-Werror=sign-promo]" which leads to lots of effort supupressing warning. Also how about to_string( bool )

Comment: @goneskiing - the code that GCC is complaining about is valid and its meaning is well defined. Keeping up with compiler writers' notions of good coding style is an endless slog.

Comment: I would also be very interested in the answer to the second part of @goneskiing 's question about why `to_string(bool)` is not included. After all many guidelines suggest not to use the 1/0 representation of bools (which is the current behaviour of `to_string`) and treat this as an implementation detail. Therefore, returning "true" or "false" would I guess be a more reasonable choice?